# Ultraproduct with respect to a partially ordered set

Tags: limits, reference-request, metric-spaces, order-theory, filters

I am interested in learning about limits with respect to ultrafilters on a poset (partially ordered set) and ultraproducts with respect to a poset. However, all I can find about this topic only consider ultrafilters on the natural numbers (more precisely, ultrafilters on the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with partial order given by set inclusion). For example, see these wikipedia articles and this blog by Terrance Tao.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/ultraproducts-as-a-bridge-between-discrete-and-continuous-analysis/

Does there exist a theory for general posets? If so, it would be much appreciated if a brief description could be provided/point to any relevant references.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)) does treat filters on general posets. But more interestingly: prove/check the Cayley-type result that every poset is a sub-poset of some powerset ordered by inclusion

Comment: My question was not about filters, but more specifically on ultraproducts. But thanks for your comment about the Cayley-type result. That does help quite a bit.